# Java OutOfMemory error in filter

Tags: java, servlets

I get a java.lang.outOfMemoryError exception, while writing a big file to the servletOutputStream.
Every response is by default wrapped using a ehcache.constructs.web.filter Object for GZIP compression. And as per the logs, the exception is thrown in the Filter object.
Is there a way to increase the available memory so, that the outOfMemoryError Exception does not occur ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the option "-Xmx1024m" to the `java` command which runs your servlet container. (Replace 1024m with whatever heap size you like; this means 1024 megabytes.) If you're using, say, Tomcat, then this means you set this in the environment variable CATALINA_OPTS. Your server configuration will vary.

However, the problem is buffering such a big file in memory. This is wasteful. Try this compression filter, which doesn't buffer this way:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjl-comp-filter/

Comment: The file is 17MB large. Should it cause a problem?
I am using a JBOSS server.

Comment: I could imagine that taking 50+MB of heap with all the intermediate data structures. And, if your heap is left at the default of about 64MB, yes, it's a problem.

While you can make the heap bigger, I really think it's better to use a filter that does not have to load the file into memory. This should not be necessary, and the filter above does not do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use -Xmx Java command line option as shown below

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx512m com.test.MyMain
```

Xms represents lower end of memory allocation and Xmx represents the upper end of memory allocation

Answer (score 0):

Set the following JVM options to your servlet container `-Xmx256m -Xms128m` (in Tomcat it is in `catalina.sh` / `catalina.bat`)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about possibly needing to increase your PermGen size:

```
-XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Also do make sure you are efficiently streaming out the file. There may be unnecessarily large buffering in the output or inputstream pipe.

Comment: There are about 24k (pretty wide) rows returned by the database, which i am writing out to the servLet Output stream. Hence, there is a gargantuan amount of data stored in the memory. 
Do you know of a way to improve this. I need all the data fetched to be sent to the webClient, in a single response . Hence i dont think i can get out bathes of data from the Database.